# Why is Python's list comprehension loop order backwards?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
>>> my_list = [[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], ]]]
>>> [a for d in my_list for c in d for b in c for a in b]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

is equivalent to

```
>>> my_list = [[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], ]]]
>>> new_list = []
>>> for d in my_list:
...     for c in d:
...         for b in c:
...             for a in b:
...                 new_list.append(a)
... print(new_list):
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This syntax seems backwards when read from left-to-right. According to [PEP 202](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/), "The form `[... for x... for y...]` nests, with the last index varying fastest, just like nested for loops." is "the Right One."

It seems that this order (of left-to-right corresponding to outer-to-inner nested for loops) was chosen because that is the order in which nested for loops are written.

However, since the expression part of the list comprehension (`a` in the above example), corresponds to the expression at the inner-most part of the nested loops (`new_list.append(a)` in the above example), it seems to me that the `for _ in _` closest to this expression should be the same in both cases, i.e. it should be `for a in b` and on outwards:

```
>>> my_list = [[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], ]]]
>>> [a for a in b for b in c for c in d for d in my_list]
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

so that the fastest-changing loop is closest to the action, so-to-speak. This also lends itself to being read from left-to-right in more logically stepwise fashion.

Is this a common sentiment among users? or does anyone have a good counter-argument as to why the current syntax implementation really is "the Right One"?

Comment: It is a BDFL pronouncement. Unless Guido posts here, all answers are speculation and opinion, I fear.

Comment: I'm imagining an alternate universe in which it was done the other way, and another user -- called `hemaj`, for example -- comes to SO and posts a question asking "Why is Python's list comprehension loop order backwards from the for loop order?"..

Comment: I expect this question will be closed, but "consistency with pre-existing `for` loop ordering" is all the answer Guido would have needed.  It would have taken a *killer* good reason to go against just that much.

Comment: I think it's important to note that ``[a for b in my_list for a in b]`` does something different from e.g. ``[a for a in (b for b in my_list)]``.  The former is actually performing a flattening action on ``my_list``, while the latter just unpacks and repacks the elements of (the elements of) ``my_list``.  That's not obvious until you think about it.

Comment: it's obvious that the latter only unpacks, this is not what is meant. we have `a` what is a? ah, `a for a in b`, ok. but what is b? now we'd expect `a for a in b for b in c`. makes sense, doesnt it?

Comment: This is why I don't use nested list comprehensions. The intuition is so backwards it takes way too long to think about how it works when debugging.

Comment: I think @mwfearnley's comment has a lot of value if the reader first understands that the comment shows something that would have to be considered if the order were the way OP wished for. That is, just swapping the parsing order would not have the desired effect on its own.

Answer (score 8):

Consider:

```
[leaf for branch in tree for leaf in branch]
```

It unrolls like:

```
for branch in tree:
    for leaf in branch:
        yield leaf
```

If we write it the other way

```
[leaf for leaf in branch for branch in tree]
```

It might make more sense in plain English on some level, but a possible counter-argument is that *here the name "branch" is used without being (yet) defined*.

Comment: This is a good point, in the sense that `for foo in bar` always defines `foo`, and expects `bar` to be already defined. Not that my opinion has changed :/

Comment: However, I could make the same argument against you - i.e. that the name `leaf` is used without being (yet) defined. (presuming we are reading from left-to-right)

Comment: Well `leaf` would be the "free variable" here, like in predicate calculus - for example, how {x: P(x)} reads like "the set of x such that P(x)"

Comment: that's precisely the reason `leaf` should go at the beginning, thanks for that comparison. I still say that the pattern {`leaf`: `leaf` in {`branch`: `branch` in `tree`}} gives a more symmetric, more readable syntax than {`leaf`: `branch` in `tree`, `leaf` in `branch`}, especially when you have 3 or more nestings.

Comment: @wim "the name "branch" is used without being (yet) defined.", wouldn't be the same with "leaf"? The for comprehension alone is that way, use first, declare right after.