# Multiple list comprehension

Tags: python

I have the following nested list:

```
items = [
   [{'URL': '1234', 'ID': 1}, {'URL': '2222', 'ID': 2}],
   [{'URL': '12344321', 'ID': 2}]
]
```

How would I get all the urls here?

So far I have tried:

```
urls = [i['URL'] for i in item for item in items]
```

Comment: related:  [Why is Python's list comprehension loop order backwards?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19484705/674039)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it in steps. First you want to flatten your outer list

```
[d for lst in items for d in lst]
# same order as if you wrote it out in a `for` loop
# for lst in items:
#     for d in lst:
#         yield d
```

this will give you a single flat list of all the dictionaries you have. Then you want to get the values tied to the key `"URL"` in each of those dictionaries. You know you can do that by using the `[key]` syntax, so just do it in the list comp.

```
[d["URL"] for lst in items for d in lst]
```

If some of those dictionaries might not have a `"URL"` key, then you can apply a filter to the end

```
[d["URL"] for lst in items for d in lst if "URL" in d]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
items = [
   [{'URL': '1234'}, {'ID': 1}],
   [{'URL': '12344321'}, {'ID': 2}]
]
print [i[0]['URL'] for i in items]
```

Grab the value of key `URL`

If you can have multiple dictionaries in single list use

```
print [j['URL'] for i in items for j in i]
```

Comment: `[d['URL'] for i in items for d in i if 'URL' in d]` if you don't know where that dictionary is

Comment: @David542 oh look, my comment answered that.

Comment: @David542 use `print [j['URL'] for i in items for j in i]`

Comment: Or maybe `filter(None, [d.get('URL') for item in items for d in item])`

Comment: Oops, I didn't see @AdamSmith's comment. Answer deleted. I don't know how both of the solutions are identical except variable names.

Answer (score 1):

If you like functional:

```
items = [
   [{'URL': '1234', 'ID': 1}, {'URL': '2222', 'ID': 2}],
   [{'URL': '12344321', 'ID': 2}]
]

from operator import itemgetter 
from itertools import chain

print(list(map(itemgetter("URL"), chain.from_iterable(items))))
['1234', '2222', '12344321']
```

`chain.from_iterable(items)` is equivalent to flattening your list of lists with a double for loop, `map(itemgetter("URL")` just pulls each `URL` value from each dicts.

Your own code  failed just because you had the logic backwards, the for over the main iterable comes first then the for over each sublist comes otherwise you are trying to iterate over something that has not yet been defined giving you a `NameError`:

```
 [i['URL'] for item in items for i in item]
```

Comment: I always think to myself "I should use `operator.itemgetter` here!" And then I write a `lambda`.

Comment: @AdamSmith, I defo prefer itemgetter, much more efficient, I am  always looking for an excuse to use it!

Comment: Unless I'm already import `operator`, trying `ggO`, `import operator`, `^O` is harder than `lambda x: x['URL']` :)

Comment: Ah the anonymous downvote with a downvote for a correct answer, well done ;)