# Why are python list comprehension control loops nested in their current form?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Why are python list comprehensions evaluated left to right? For example, correct syntax is:

```
[item for sublist in superlist for item in sublist]
```

But it seems more intuitve to me to have the following:

```
[item for item in sublist for sublist in superlist]
```

Because it is analagous to the following:

```
[[item for item in sublist] for sublist in superlist]
```

Which is also valid python.

Comment: Probably consistency with normal for-loop ordering? Try unwinding the loops from left to right, and it seems pretty intuitive. This question will probably yield nothing more than speculation though.

Comment: "Because it is analagous to the following:" <speculation>Maybe it is exactly so that it is easier to differentiate from that.</speculation>

Comment: @Mitch it's not pure speculation because Guido's rationale is documented - see answer below.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2:  Guido's decision is documented, but not the reasoning behind his decsion.  I ammended my answer with a deeper historical dive but I still could not find the root of the *why*.

Comment: @Mitch:  I say leave this open.  If you look at my answer it's at least possible to give a history lesson that isn't opinion based.

Comment: I'm voting to move this question to Programmers

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Your answer is great :) and I agree with your statement, but IMHO the question is still ultimately opinion based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first place to look is in [PEP 202: List Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/).  In the PEP the BDFL (Guido van Rossum) pronounces that:

> The form `[... for x... for y...]` nests, with the last index varying fastest, just like nested `for` loops.

But this doesn't tell us *why*.  Guido van Rossum tells us in The History of Python [From List Comprehensions to Generator Expressions](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html) that

> List comprehensions were added in Python 2.0. This feature
>   **originated as a set of patches by Greg Ewing** with contributions by Skip Montanaro and Thomas Wouters. (IIRC Tim Peters also strongly
>   endorsed the idea.)

Greg Ewing published [Python List Comprehensions Enhancement](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/listcomp/) in September 1999:

> This enhancement extends the syntax of Python 1.5.2 to include what
>   are known in some other languages as list comprehensions. Here are
>   some examples:
>
> ```
> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
> fruit = ["Apple", "Banana", "Pear"]
> mult3 = [3 * x for x in numbers]
> evens = [x for x in numbers if x % 2 == 0]
> crossprod = [(x, y) for x in numbers for y in fruits]
> ```

And further on

> The semantics are such that the statement
>
> ```
> x = [e for v1 in s1 for v2 in s2 ... if t ...]
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> x = []
> for v1 in s1:
>   for v2 in s2:
>     ...
>       if t:
>         ...
>           x.append(e)
> ```

Again note that Greg Ewing doesn't tell us *why* the for-loops have the order that they do.  He simply presents the idea fully formed.  Perhaps the clue lies in his allusion to "what are known in some other languages as list comprehensions".

I also skimmed through the entire discussion in the python-dev mailing list that preceded the addition of list comprehensions and I could not get to the bottom of this.  There was some argument whether nesting should be allowed at all.  There as an interesting rabbit trail about a proposed syntax for parallel processing in list comprehensions that was rejected when they realized they could just invent the builtin `zip`.  There was no argument about the order of the loops.

No matter the reason why for the ordering, the order of the for-loops in a list comprehension follow the order they would appear in normal for-loops.

```
result = []
for sublist in superlist:
    for item in superlist:
        result.append(item)
```

becomes

```
result = [item for sublist in superlist for item in sublist]
```

Another way to look at is that regular for-loops nest with increasing indentation.  Increasing indentation is a move from left to right.  In the same way nesting in comprehensions is accomplished by structuring from left to right.

**Note:** This question was also addressed in [Why is Python's list comprehension loop order backwards? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484705/why-is-pythons-list-comprehension-loop-order-backwards?rq=1).  One of the people who voted to close the question as "primarily opinion based" was Tim Peters, who Guido van Rossum credits as being one of the champions of adding list comprehensions to Python.  So you're not going to get a definitive answer on this one.

Answer (score 2):

According to [PEP 202: List Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/#rationale) (see "rationale"), the [BDFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life) has decreed that:

> The form `[... for x... for y...]` nests, with the last index varying fastest, just like nested `for` loops.