# How can I concatenate all of the responses from (Python's) iter_tools.product()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I'm trying generate a list of all possible combinations of characters over a several lengths using Python 2.7. For the sake of example, I'm using a much smaller subset to proof the concept.

Below I generate all combinations of the letters from A-C, of lengths 1 and 2. I then try to generate one list using a second for loop in the same generator comprehension (wrong term?). I can get all of the strings of a single length into a list, but I get the error `an integer is required` when trying

How do I concatenate all these responses from each of the levels of `repeat` in the product generator function?

```
>>> l
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> p1 = (''.join(p) for p in product(l, repeat=1))
>>> p2 = (''.join(p) for p in product(l, repeat=2))
>>> [str(i) for i in p1]
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> [str(i) for i in p2]
['AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC']
>>> pn = (''.join(p) for p in product(l, repeat=i) for i in range(1,3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Yes, I could do this with nested for loops. I'm trying to do it with one-liners, since I saw a similar example with what looked like a generator comprehension. I've used list comprehensions before - but when I feed it nested list comprehensions, I get lists of long strings of the entire lists of combinations smashed together.

It could also be that I don't understand iterator functions correctly, because I struggled to get those debug list comprehensions correct on lines 5 and 7 in my code example.

Comment: Well, do you know where the TypeError is coming from? Is it i that is the issue?  is it l? is it the result of product (assuming it is iterable?).  Maybe you might want to use the enumerate function?

Comment: The type error is from the `repeat` parameter. When I set it to an int it works, but obviously doesn't iterate through...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have you for-loops the wrong way around in your generator expression, they "nest" from left to right:

```
>>> g = (''.join(p) for i in range(1, 3) for p in product(l, repeat=i))
>>> list(g)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC']
```

Comment: Because of this, the original code was referencing `i` from the *first* list comprehension in the snippet, so it had the value 'CC'.

Comment: Dang, I could have sworn nested for loops in generators went the other way. Do they go the other way in list comprehensions? Maybe that's where I screwed up...(?)

Comment: While this is completely right, I think it reads completely backwards. Do you know the reason for this nesting order in Python?

Comment: @user3.1415927 No, they are the same in list-comps and yes it does take some getting used to :)

Comment: @JohanL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484705/why-is-pythons-list-comprehension-loop-order-backwards

Comment: @JoeIddon Ah, thanks. This is one of those "dutch" things, I suppose...

Comment: @JohanL "dutch" things?

Comment: @JoeIddon From the zen of Python: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch."

Comment: @JohanL Ah, I see :)